# Including resources folder in apk

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm writing a hybrid application in Cordova using Intel XDK. I've found and installed plugin for displaying native notifications on device, but got stuck with problem concerning icons customization. I am supposed to use *Local resource for native resources relative to the res/drawable/ (Android) or Resources/ (iOS) folder*.

And here comes the problem, because I can not make Intel XDK to add anything into the `res` folder inside .apk. I've found out that I should create appropriate folder structure (`platforms/android/res/drawable`) and place there my icon, but unfortunately one is not loaded in the .apk. How to build application so my own resources would be included? Am I missing some xml config or settings?

[Plugin Link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

Comment: quick google search have you seen this page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/cordova-for-android-build-options

Comment: I've seen this, but there is nothing in fact that would solve my problem.

Comment: But what I found is that it is currently impossible to do in Intel XDK: https://software.intel.com/es-es/forums/intel-xdk/topic/562433

Answer (score 0):

Despite the statements [in the forum post](https://software.intel.com/es-es/forums/intel-xdk/topic/562433), it may be possible to do what you are asking about, but not without some effort. The forum post is correct, there is no way to add custom images, for use by the plugin you are trying to use, in your XDK project as described by the plugin docs. In the case of an XDK project, the platform directories pointed to by those plugin docs exist only in the build system, where it uses Cordova CLI to build your app, they do not exist in your local XDK project directory (despite the resemblance to a Cordova CLI project, your local project directory is missing the platform folders).

To do this you'd have to create a simple plugin, that will add those resources into the respective platform folder locations at build time. I'd have to spend some time figuring out precisely how to do this, which I don't have time for right now, but at least wanted to help you give it a try, if you are up for it. :-)

The simplest way to figure this out would be to inspect a plugin that adds custom graphic images to the built app it is being included in. The inAppBrowser is one you could use as a guide, certainly there are others. Inspect the [`plugin.xml` file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/plugin.xml) for that pluginand find the Android platform section where it copies files from the plugin's `src` directory into the platform's `res` directory. In essence, what you want to do is create a small custom plugin that contains a `plugin.xml` file that includes such directives, plus the custom images you want to copy into the respective locations for each platform. So you'd also have an `src/android/res/etc...` directory containing your Android images, and so on for the other platforms. You may have to look at a few plugins to see how this is done for other platforms.

Here's the plugin guide, most of which you won't need, just the bits to create a basic `plugin.xml` file and the local images you want to add to your app >  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

You'll then have to add this plugin as a "local" plugin to your project, using the Plugin Manager tool. Do not develop your plugin inside the `<project>/plugins` directory, that is a destination. Develop it somewhere else, either inside your project (e.g., `<project>/my-custom-icons`) or somewhere outside the project. The Plugin Manager doesn't care where it is located, as long as it is somewhere on your local dev system and NOT inside the `<project>/plugins` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a solution for this problem in this thread:
[res/drawable files in Intel XDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395820/res-drawable-files-in-intel-xdk/40132034#40132034)

Altough I have not yet tested this on iOS, the solution should be similar.