# res/drawable files in Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, notifications, intel-xdk

Is there a way in xdk to transfer files to the android/res/drawable folder?

I've the following files:

```
src/android/drawable/noti_icon.png
www/src/android/drawable/noti_icon.png
```

And I've tryed it by including the following lines in my intelxdk.config.additions.xml file

```
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable/noti_icon.png"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png"/>

<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="res/drawable"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="res/drawable-hdpi"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="res/drawable-xhdpi"/>

<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png"/>

<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="platforms/android/res/drawable"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi"/>
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi"/>


<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable/noti_icon.png"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png"/>

<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="res/drawable"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="res/drawable-hdpi"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="res/drawable-xhdpi"/>

<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png"/>

<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="platforms/android/res/drawable"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi"/>
<source-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon.png" target-dir="platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi"/>
```

But nothing happens. Should it work or is it all wrong? What can I do? I need this icon for my local notifications.

Comment: Did you end up getting this working? I have the same problem

Comment: Not realy. I've cloned cordova-plugin-local-notifications an added:

        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon_18.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/noti_icon.png"/>
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon_24.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/noti_icon.png"/>
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon_36.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png"/>
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable/noti_icon_48.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png"/>

to plugin.xml. Put the src to the root folder of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is part of the solution to a popular problem with the [local notifications plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) in Intel XDK. 
The [wiki](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/10.-URIs) tells us that there are 3 possibilities to load the notification icon, but only when using the res type it seemed to work for me. I haven't found any other clear solution on this and I haven't been able to test it on iOS, but here is what I did on Android:

1. I located the plugin folder in my Intel XDK project (de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification for me, but I'll call it local-notification from now on).
2. Created android res folder: local-notification\src\android\res
3. Since I'm still not sure about all the different resolutions, I created 4 folders: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi and put my differently sized icons in them. So in the end I had f.e.: local-notification/src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png
4. Now I followed Tom's instructions and the hint given [in this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995548/including-resources-folder-in-apk) and added the following lines to local-notification\plugin.xml file:

   ```
   <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/noti_icon.png" />
   <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-mdpi/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/noti_icon.png" />
   <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/noti_icon.png" />
   <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/noti_icon.png" target="res/drawable-xxhdpi/noti_icon.png" />
   ```

The icon is now finally available as ressource and can be used via the res type with the local notifcations plugin by simply:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    ...your other options... ,
    icon: "noti_icon",
    smallicon:"noti_icon"
});
```

(You don't need to add the filetype or "res://" type)

Finally, instead of seeing the Android bell icon, you should now see your own icon.

There are some other google guidelines to take care of, like a transparent background on your .png, but I'm not sure and haven't tested if these specs have any influence on the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I beilive this question is asked to get over the nasty white icon of a cordova app when it receive a push notification.

One painless way is to use this popular plugin to register and receive push notifications: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Then  just simply put the icon somewhere in your apps's folder and when sending the message from your push server, specify the icon by the image property like this:

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["my device id"],
    "data": {
        "title": "Large Icon",
        "message": "Loaded from assets folder",
        "image": "www/image/logo.png"
    }
}
```

You can reffer to this link:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md